# как сделать выполнение своих php скриптов в yii2

Tags: yii2

в проекте yii2 есть необходимость выполнять свои скрипты. ну например для расчета каких то показателей (брать их из базы и потом отбратно запихивать в базу). в первой версии фреймворка были хелперы, которые можно было создать. во второй есть встроенные хелперы. но как использовать свои хелперы и для начала создать их.

Comment: Просто создаете новый класс, прописываете в нем namespace "papka_s_helperami/helpers" и вызываете по этому пространству имен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброе утро.

Например, можно создать свой компонент. Прописать его в конфигурационном файле и вызывать в нужных местах проекта.
Создаёте директорию или файл в папке components

```
<php
  namespace app\components;
  use yii\base\Component;

  class MyComponent extends Component
  {
     public function setBase()
     {
       // записываете данные в базу
     }

     public function getBase()
     {
       // получаете данные из базы
     } 
  }
?>
```

В конфигурационном файле прописываете свой компонент

```
'components' => [
  // другие настройки приложения
  'myComponent' => [
     'class' => 'app\components\MyComponent'
  ]
]
```

Вызываете свой компонент в нужном месте проекта

```
Yii::$app->myConponent->getBase();
```

Можно дополнительно передавать разные параметры, которые необходимы для работы класса.

Вот как-то так.

p.s. Пример для yii2-basic.

p.s.s.
Можно не делать компонент, а создать просто класс, разместить файл хотя бы в той же components. Но ничего не надо прописывать в конфигурационном файле, методы в классе static. Подключать в нужном месте через use

Comment: спасибо за ответ. а можно ли сделать это через типа "контроллеры-хелперы ". ну то есть будут созданы отдлеьные файлы контроллеры в другой папке и будут вызываться как методы класса. просто таких вот "скриптов" надо много создать.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо. примерно так и начали реализовывать. посмотрим что получтся в итоге

Comment: Всё получится)))

Comment: Таким макаром Вы можете переопределить какой-то базовый класс yii и использовать уже свой. Например для формирования колонок в gridview.